# Django permission and authorization

Tags: django

I am working on Django project and I want to make model-based permission, my question is if I have an app named order, the default permissions are add_order,change_order,delete_order and view_order, so are those permission exists only for the admin side? I mean if try to delete a model object from order app in my view, not in the admin, what will happen, and if so I want to know if it will cause any errors? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, Django permissions are not implicitly checked in your own views, you have to apply the logic yourself.

You have a few options for checking the permissions:

- User.has_perm(permission)
- Perms template tag
- The permission_required decorator
- The PermissionRequiredMixin

More information can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin